# How to find bottleneck for parallel curl command?

Tags: dns, curl

I got curl runing like this:

```
parallel -j0 curl -x 10.9.8.4:8080 --retry 1 --connect-timeout 3 -I https://{} --output {}
```

which results in 1000 parallel jobs. I've already incereased ulimit -n to 4096 so -j0 in parallel command runs 1000 parallel jobs.

Now I only got this:

```
while true; do ls | wc -l; sleep 1; done                                                               
62040
62242
62424
62603
62764
62920
```

Which equals around 120 - 200 request per second.

I got NVMe drives - my suspect is DNS resolver - I got local Bind DNS resolver with DNS top but with no useful results.

I've dumped cache of my local BIND and 80% of domains which will be requested are there - so maybe I am looking into wrong area.

Where should I look next?

I got enough computing power - 4.6GHz 64G RAM NVMe drives.

Comment: `fork()` is far from free... (though on Linux it's significantly lighter than on Windows)... If you wrote a quick Python script (or similar) that dealt with this all in one process (or with recycled workers) you'd likely have much better results.

Comment: It's easy enough to determine where the source of the problem might be... try running `dig +short ${HOST}` and `curl ${URL}` in a loop, and use `time` to get a feel for which takes longer.

Comment: In addition to that, your machine cannot execute 1000 threads simultaneously, so reducing that figure dramatically may actually improve your stats..

Comment: You could also use `curl`'s `-w` flag to get information on where the time is spent within the process (excludes the aforementioned `fork()`, etc...)